# Maximum Throughput of QAM system

Tags: modulation, amplitude, channelcoding, quadrature

Consider a QAM system designed to transmit over a bandwidth of $3 \ \mathrm{kHz}$. The channel's power constraint imposes a maximum $\mathrm{SNR}$ of $30 \ \mathrm{dB}$. The system can tolerate a probability of error of $10^{−6}$. I want to determine the maximum throughput of the system in bits per second.

Let's call the throughput $T$. If $M$ is the constellation size and $"$ is the bandwidth, then I know that $T=MW$. I've calculated the value of $M$ using theformula $$M = \log_2 \left( 1 - \frac{1.5\mathrm{SNR}}{\ln(p_e)}\right)$$ Then I approximated $M$ to the nearest power of $2$, which is $8$.
Therefore, $T = 24000 \ \mathrm{\frac{bits}{sec}}$
but it is a wrong answer. Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $\log_2(M)$ is even, the relationship betweeen BER and QAM if an AWGN channel is given as below (Assuming Gray coding so that a symbol error in most cases is one bit error):

\begin{align}
k&=\log_2(M)\\
y &= 10^{\frac{SNR}{10}}\\
P_e&=\frac{4}{k}\frac{\sqrt{M}-1}{2\sqrt{M}}\textrm{erfc}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3k\frac{y}{M-1}}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{align}

Using the above formula to solve for $y$ given your SNR and constellation $M$ should achieve the result you are looking for.

[This](http://www.dsplog.com/2012/01/01/symbol-error-rate-16qam-64qam-256qam/) is an excellent explanation for the derivation of the formula, specific to QAM.

And [here](http://www.embedded.com/print/4017668) is a nice summary by the same author for BER vs SNR of many different modulation schemes

Comment: Still wrong answer

Comment: Please tell us what the right answer is and maybe we can see what the difference is.

Comment: I don't know the right answer... It is an online quiz where I input my solutions and it shows correct or wrong only

Comment: I used your formula and got 6.77 for M; did you use 1000 for SNR?

Comment: I forgot to convert SNR and used it in db .. you are right according to the formula M = 6.77 and approximating it to 8 so throughput will equal 24,000 bits/sec but it isn't also correct ... it is very frustrating and I've been searching all day but I can't solve it

Comment: Try the exact answer of 6.77, and then try 6, and 7

Comment: @MohamedMaherz If $M$ has to be a power of 2, then surely the answer is $M=4$? Going with $M>6.77$ will cause the bit error rate to be larger than the requirement; you need to "round" down.

Comment: No argument there, but simple enough to try since you do not know what answer they are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Dan, 18000 was the correct answer which means M = 6!

Comment: Yes that makes sense; note that M itself does not need to be a power of two, just an integer. k is a power of two and is the number of points in the constellation (in your case 2^6 = 64 (64-QAM). Glad it all worked out!